# Javascript regex for input element pattern attribute works on reFiddle but not on page

Tags: javascript, regex, html, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to use the following regex to allow some basic feedback for users filling in a form:

```
/\+?[(]?(?:[0-9\ ][a-z]?[()\-\.]?){3,}/ig
```

(I'm aware of [this point](https://stackoverflow.com/a/123681/2861073) about regexes for phone numbers; my purpose here is just to allow some feedback for the user by highlighting the input box green or red, not to ensure real phone-numbers are entered).

This regex seems to behave exactly how I want on https://regex101.com/r/mpL6vv/1, but when I use it on the page, it seems to find everything invalid:

```
<input type='tel' name='phone' required pattern='/\+?[(?:]?([0-9a-z\ ][()\-\.]?){3,}/ig' />
```

This is being used as part of Zurb Foundation's Abide form validation. The page has many other inputs with various patterns, and they all seem to validate / invalidate correctly.

Could anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong that's causing the regex pattern to invalidate everything? Thanks.

Comment: Could someone say why this is getting downvoted and how I could make it a better question? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use javascript delimiters (or modifiers) in the html `pattern` object. For the pattern to work, remove the delimiter and javascript modifiers, like so:

```
\+?[(?:]?([0-9a-z\ ][()\-\.]?){3,}
```

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/remus/dPZC7/ (press submit to check).

Comment: Thanks, silly mistake! I went with `<input type='tel' name='phone' pattern='\+?[(]?(?:[0-9\ ][a-zA-Z]?[()\-\.]?){5,}' />`